# Odd behavior observed using metadata API to retrieve contact record types

Tags: metadata-api

I have observed some odd behavior with retrieval of contact record types. I have created three contact record types which i can see in my org and via the workbench. If i use a wild card as follows, none of the contact record types are retrieved. Record types for all other objects are retrieved successfully:

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>RecordType</name>
</types>
```

Yet, if i explixcitly name just one of the contact record types as follows, all three are contact record types are retrieved. Is this a feature, or a bug?

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <members>Contact.Customer_Contact</members>
    <name>RecordType</name>
</types>
```

To be clear, the above xml retrieves all three of my contact record types, yet a solo wild card doesn't retieve any of them.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more like a bug whenever you specify one record type and get them all. The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_recordtype.htm) states that:

> This metadata type doesn’t support the wildcard character * (asterisk) in the package.xml manifest file. For information about using the manifest file, see Deploying and Retrieving Metadata with the Zip File.

As such, the wildcard is meant to have no effect. I find it interesting that you got all three record types when you specified just one.

The ordinary way to get all record types for an object is to get the object itself:

```
<types>
    <members>Contact</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
```

The [CustomObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customobject.htm) metadata itself returns all **custom** objects with a wildcard, but standard objects have to be explicitly named.

If you're using DX, you'll get a very handy output with:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomObject:Contact
```

As the record types will all be in their own folder (e.g. force-app/main/default/objects/Contact/recordTypes) for further processing.